# Raspberry Pi 3B WiFi Problem

Tags: pi-3, wifi

Relative newbie, just completed my first simple sensor project that outputs data to the web whilst connected via Ethernet. Now I'm trying to move this setup to a WiFi connection which I thought might be the easy part, but I'm stuck...

I've played around with `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`, but I can't seem to get a connection via wlan0 whatever I do. I've tried multiple different options, with output for iconfig and current contents of these files below. When `ifdown wlan0` I get `ifdown: interface wlan0 not configured`.

Any help much appreciated.

Update 06/09 - now added `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`. I'm using SSID=VM321716-2G_EXT.

**`iconfig wlan0`**

```
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 169.254.224.240  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
    inet6 fe80::e1c9:f258:85c5:4e5a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether b8:27:eb:d2:05:21  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 383  bytes 62895 (61.4 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 521  bytes 63660 (62.1 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**`/etc/network/interfaces`**

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

**`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`**

```
country=GB
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev

update_config=1

network={
 ssid="mySSID"
 psk="mypassword"
 key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

**`sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`**

```
wlan0     Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: E8:FC:AF:3A:A9:90
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=70/70  Signal level=-13 dBm
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"VM321716-2G"
....
      Cell 02 - Address: 34:8A:AE:CF:8F:B7
                Channel:1
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"BTHub5-ZP9Z"
....
      Cell 03 - Address: 9C:3D:CF:F1:AE:98
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"VM321716-2G_EXT"
.....
```

Comment: what is the output from `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`

Comment: now updated with sudo iwlist wlan0 scan

Comment: I cant see a ESSID that is named "mySSID" that `wpa_supplicant.conf` have. You need to add ESSID and password for your WiFi network into `wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: And if you add a @ and my nic (MatsK) then I get a notice that you have made a new comment. Like this `@MatsK`

Answer (score 1):

### Tweak `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

First, I would replace `ssid="mySSID"` with `ssid="VM321716-2G_EXT"`.
Also, make sure you replace `mypassword` with your wifi network's password.

If that didn't fix it, try removing the `key_mgmt=WPA-PSK` line from `wpa_supplicant.conf` because I don't think it's needed.  If that fixes it, great!  Otherwise, keep reading...

---

### Check Password

It's dumb, but we all do it.  Make sure you typed in the password correctly.  If so, read on!

---

### Link Local Address

This line in your `ifconfig wlan0` output indicates a DHCP problem:

`inet 169.254.224.240  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255`

IP addresses in that 169.254.x.x range [(*Link Local*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) is what computers use when they failed to get an address via DHCP and there was no static fallback address configured.

### Check `dhcpcd`

Assuming the other computers on your wifi are able to get to the Internet just fine, it's likely an issue on the raspberry pi.

`dhcpcd` is the service that handles getting a proper address from the DHCP server running on your wifi network (usually on the wifi router.)
You can check to make sure it's running with `sudo systemctl status dhcpcd`:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo systemctl status dhcpcd
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d
           └─wait.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-05-07 21:45:24 UTC; 4 months 0 days ago
 Main PID: 591 (dhcpcd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
           └─591 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -w
```

If it's not running, use `sudo systemctl enable dhcpcd` to make sure it runs at boot time and then reboot.

If it's already running, check the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` configuration file to make sure it's not misconfigured.
The default contents of that file are:

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU.
# Some interface drivers reset when changing the MTU so disabled by default.
#option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

# A hook script is provided to lookup the hostname if not set by the DHCP
# server, but it should not be run by default.
nohook lookup-hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the below methods to troubleshoot the problem. This is very unprofessional but i hope it can help to pinpoint the problem.

***Trial and error method 0 (problem: need to reload /etc/network/interfaces)

1. `ifdown wlan0`
2. `systemctl restart networking`
3. `ifup wlan0`
4. `ping 8.8.8.8`

***Trial and error method 1 (problem: need to run dhcpcd)***

1. Remove line `key_mgmt=WPA-PSK`
2. `ifup wlan0`
3. `dchcpd wlan0`
4. `ping 8.8.8.8`

***Trial and error method 2 (problem: need to run dhcpcd)***

1. Remove line `key_mgmt=WPA-PSK`
2. Change line `iface wlan0 inet dhcp`
3. `ifup wlan0`
4. `ping 8.8.8.8`

***Trial and error method 3 (problem: need wpa_supplicant & dhcp)***

1. Remove line `key_mgmt=WPA-PSK`
2. `ifup wlan0`
3. `wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`
4. `dhcpcd wlan0`
5. `ping 8.8.8.8`

***Trial and error method 4 (probelm: need to assign static address)***

1. Remove line `key_mgmt=WPA-PSK`
2. `ifup wlan0`
3. `ifconfig wlan0 192.168.x.x` (desired static ip address)
4. `route add default gw 192.168.x.x` (ip of gateway)
5. `ping 8.8.8.8`

***Trial and error method 5 (problem: need wpa_supplicant & static)***

1. Remove line `key_mgmt=WPA-PSK`
2. `ifup wlan0`
3. `wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`
4. `ifconfig wlan0 192.168.x.x` (desired static ip address)
5. `route add default gw 192.168.x.x` (ip of gateway)
6. `ping 8.8.8.8`